# How to list dropdown menu by files in same folder and show in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have index.html and intend to list all .HTML files(excluding index.html) in the same folder and show in a dropdown menu inside an `iframe`.

Any suggestion?, Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't do this with html. You need an app server to do it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML runs in the user's browser. At that point your file structure is unavailable, because the browser is possibly on another computer. Instead you need to do something different.

An approach is to implement a POST request on your server, which provides the data your dropdown needs and request it with [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). An even simpler approach is to generate HTML by some server-side code and thus create your dropdown. That could be a page on its own, which can be requested as the `src` of an `iframe`.